# How to make POST with array as header and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-headers, afnetworking

This is the header:

```
                "url": "{{host}}/images/bla",
            "method": "POST",
            "header": [
                {
                    "key": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/json",
                    "description": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "Authorization",
                    "value": "Bearer token",
                    "description": ""
                }
            ],
            "body": { ... }
```

I tried to solve it in two cases:

**Case 1** (crashes):

```
NSDictionary *headerDict = @{@"key": @"Content-Type",
                                 @"value": @"application/json",
                                 @"description": @""};

NSDictionary *headerDict1 = @{@"key": @"Authorization",
                                 @"value": kBearerKey,
                                 @"description": @""};
NSArray *headerArray = @[headerDict, headerDict1];

[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:headerArray forHTTPHeaderField:@"header"];
```

**Case 2** (doesn't crashes but doesn't work too):

```
weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key"];
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"value"];
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Authorization" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key"];
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:kBearerKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"value"];
```

Anyway, in *Case 1* a warning is generated (and a crash too) because `setValue` is expected to be `NSString` not `NSArray`.

Comment: you need to convert array into json string : NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: headerArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: This is working but the problem is the data interpreter add a "\" to @"application/json" and it looks like @"application\/json" : (lldb) po headerString
[
  {
    "key" : "Content-Type",
    "value" : "application\/json",
    "description" : ""
  },
  {
    "key" : "Authorization",
    "value" : "Bearer xpkaVSckJSfCWzcXfODtiBu38B6mOMzPW....",
    "description" : ""
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all the header values in NSMutableDictionary as key/Value pair for example

```
NSDictionary *headersDict = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/json",
                                  @"Authorization": kBearerKey };
```

Then you can iterate key values and set http headers

```
[headersDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [requestManager.requestSerializer setValue:obj forHTTPHeaderField:key];
    }];
```

In your case you're using an array.. You can iterate array and set header values, hope this helps.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in headerArray) {

        NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
        NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"value"];

        [requestManager.requestSerializer setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
NSError *error;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization:headerArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];                                                                                 

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"header"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**AFNetworking 3**

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: headerArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:nil error:nil];

req.timeoutInterval= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:req
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[[error valueForKey:@"userInfo"] valueForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                  } else {
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *headerDict = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/json", @"Authorization": kBearerKey};
```

OR

```
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[weakSelf.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:kBearerKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: try this `weakSelf.requestOperationManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];`